# no me reconoce mi TextBoxNombre y TextBoxclave en .net windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

trato de realizar un login sencillo con conexion a sql server
la cuestion es que cuando mando a llamar mis botones en el diseño de mi boton entrar, este simplemente no me los reconoce

codigo form1.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }


      

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         

    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=JOSUE; database=prueba; integrated security=true Password=locasilolees");
    conexion.Open();
    string consulta="select nombre,clave from usuario where nombre='"+TextBoxNombre.Text+"'and clave='"+TextBoxclave.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
    SqlDataReader registros = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (registros.Read())
    {
    Form2 abrir = new Form2();
    abrir.Show();
    this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show("El nombre o La contraseña no existen");
    }
    } 

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    registrarUsuario nuevo = new registrarUsuario();
    nuevo.Show();
    this.Hide();
    }
    }
    }
```

aqui muestro el error que me presenta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### mi formulario se llama Form1
y mis botones de tipo text se llaman TextBoxNombre y TextBoxclave
los cuales al haceer la consulta a la base de datos este los manda a llamar para agregar los datos de los inputs del formulario

aqui dejo ejemplos de las propiedades que me manda cuando selecciono TextBox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada, debes parametrizar las consultas sql . Luego haz lo siguiente : dale doble click encima a alguno de los Textbox que tiene en el formulario y con eso el Visual Studio debería crear un método, cuando le genere el método por favor agregue la foto del código que le generó.

Comment: me aparecen varias propiedades agregar lo adjunte en la pregunta arriba

Comment: No hiciste lo que te pedí. Si quieres que te ayude dale doble click encima a alguno de los Textbox y muestra el código generado. Porque les dice botones de tipo text ??? Son botones o son Textbox ????

Comment: a ya si sierto ya lo correji

Answer (score 0):

Ahí esta tu respuesta. Tus textbox se llaman Nombre y clave. Por lo que tu código debe ser algo así:

```
string consulta="select nombre,clave from usuario where nombre='"+Nombre.Text+"'and clave='"+clave.Text + "'";
```

Y por favor no olvide parametrizar la consulta.

Comment: perfecto muy amable gracias